# List Matching a field

Tags: c#, .net, list

I need to match field returned from `fields` with `sometext`.

Below is what I have attempted

```
public interface IProjectData
    {
        string field { get; set; }
        string fieldName { get; set; }
        string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProjectData : IProjectData
    {
        public ProjectData();

        public string field { get; set; }
        public string fieldName { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
var fields = new List<MarinaAPI.MarinaAPI.ProjectData>();
fields = SomeClassApi.Get(code, "TG");
var selectedField1 = fields.Single(x => x.field.Contains("sometext"));
```

But I'm getting an error:

> sequence contains no matching elements

How do I correct my code to get the `field` with value matching `sometext`

Comment: I have updated the error, sorry the old one was from different project.

Comment: A matchin element exists in field as 'fadein_4'

Comment: Sorry my bad, this is not a valid question. I fixed it by using tolower, it was different case. Just having a bad day. Sorry guy for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to replicate this locally. Can `SomeClassApi.Get();` return null? If so, then you should be using `fields.SingleOrDefault(x => x.field.contains("sometext"));`. If the value of fields is null and you call just `.Single()` then you will get a run time error. A different error than what you are getting here, but that's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: You have a valid point, im accepting this answer. Even though i fixed it using tolower(). But i should change my code as per your instruction to make it better

Comment: ok cool, if that is the error you are getting than it will be fixed by utilizing the `SingleOrDefault`. Only use `Single()` if you know there is 100% a match, otherwise it throws this error.

Comment: Thanks bro. Undestood